# In Microsoft Teams App Studio, unable to change Bot endpoint address

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

While editing the "Bot endpoint address" in App studio in Microsoft teams application, the new url is accepted but not persisted!! so it shows the old url when navigate away and return back to "Bots" tab.
please find screenshot below

[image: App Studio page in Microsoft Teams on Mac. the endpoint field is marked and showing the old url]

When i tried from the web version of Teams, I got the following error in console:

> POST https://appstudio.azurefd.net/api/botframework/7fadd602-e2b8-49bf-94d6-58016dbce4a2 500

This feature was working till yesterday.
I am hosting the app locally using ngrok and the url is responding.

I have also tried to remove the bot & the application from Teams but no good.
I have tried to uninstall Teams :( and install it again but no good.

This behavior is tested in Mac and Web versions.

Comment: I experience this as well, although have not tried it previously. However, the endpoint input field shows success. Can you verify that the endpoint doesn't change when installing the bot, despite the 500 error? If not, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ahmed Abbas We had a regression which is fixed now. This should be working now. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can change this, for sure, is to go to `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your Web App Bot (or Bot Channels Registration) > Settings`, change the endpoint there, then re-install your bot in App Studio.

Comment: just to add my observations, it works even without reinstalling the bot app in Teams